# Why King Solomon wasn't worthy of a share in Olam Haba?

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come, maseches-sanhedrin, king-solomon

In [Sanhedrin 104](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.104b.13?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en), the members of the Great Assembly decided that Shlomo does not deserve a share in the World to Come.

> [*Sages enumerated a list of kings that do not deserve a share in Olam Habah]* Rav Ashi says: The members of the Great Assembly enumerated them. Rav Yehuda says that Rav says: They sought to enumerate one more, King Solomon...
>
> A Divine Voice emerged and said to the members of the Great Assembly: ... "Therefore, “he shall stand before kings; he shall stand not before obscure men,” and it is inappropriate **to enumerate him among the wicked**.

Why did the Sages consider King Solomon so wicked that he lost his share in the WTC?

Comment: I won't pretend to understand it but I get the sense that this site suggests an answer https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.104b.13?lang=bi&with=Likutei%20Maamarim&lang2=en

Comment: @rosends I tried to understand it also but couldn't.

Comment: Idol worship is pretty bad, no?

Comment: @JoelK Allegedly, you mean. Still doesn't add up.

Comment: @JoelK On the one hand, he didn’t actually worship idols (which may be why he kept his Olam Haba); on the other hand, what he *did* do is compared to idolatry on his level (which may be why the Sages thought he did lose it).

Comment: @DonielF I know what (some of) Chazal say about it. I also know what *pshat* in Melachim says

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83040/paskening-shlomo-out-of-shamayim

Comment: VTC, this is a dupe of the question @Maurice cites above. Good work, Mizrahi!

Answer (score -1):

Idol worship is one of the worst things to offend Gd, as it's the second commandment. Chazal had to weigh out Shlomo's qualities against his bad traits, which included idolatry at the end of his life. Regarding those that have no share in the World to Come, see https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.10.1?lang=bi

Comment: I'm open to why my comment was downvoted?